# Showing a multivariable function is constant under a condition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, multivalued-functions

let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function. and we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x }=  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$. Prove that function $g(x,y) = f(x,y,a)$ for fixed real number $a$ is a constant function.

I really don't have any idea to solve this. Although I know it must be straight forward. Is this enough to say that derivative of $g$ is zero? If yes, Should I use partial derivative?

Comment: I think you solved your own question. It's a multivariate function so it really doesn't make sense to say THE derivative is zero. Look at the partial derivatives and interpret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is a $C^1$ function, then so is $g$. And since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ everywhere, then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ everywhere. But then the derivative of $g$ is $0$ everywhere, and therefore $g$ is constant.

Comment: Is this enough? I see one solution that used $\gamma(t) $ and $\gamma(0) = x$ , $\gamma (1) = y$ and then said we get derivatives of  $h(t) = g(\gamma (t))$ and it is $h'(t) = \gamma' (t) \nabla g(\gamma (t)) = 0$ so $h(0) = h(1)$ so $g(x) = g(y)$. And I get really confused with this solution that why it used g(x) for a multivariable function. I was thinking of a solution like yours but completely get confused by that solution.

Comment: I think that what I wrote is enough. What you wrote justifies why is it that a function with all partial derivatives equal to $0$ everywhere is constant. It all depends upon whether you can use that fact or not.

Comment: My problem is that what is $g(x)$ in the proof in comment ? Isn't g a multivariable function? then what is g(x) in that proof?

Comment: It's the same function $g$ that appears in your question.

Comment: Then where is the second variable? is x a vector?

Comment: In your first comment, both $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathbb R^2$.